# How to study the monotonicity of $c_{n+1} = \sqrt{2+\frac{c_n}{3}}$ given that $c_1 =5$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am studying the monotonicity of $c_{n+1} = \sqrt{2+\frac{c_n}{3}} = \sqrt{\frac{6+c_n}{3}}$, given than $c_1 = 5$

---

I proved by induction that $c_n > 0$.

**My attempt**

Lets make the hypothesis that:
$$ \frac{c_{n+1}}{c_n} = \sqrt{\frac{6+c_n}{3c_n^2}}  < 1 \iff \frac{6+c_n}{3c_n^2} < 1 $$. Still that seems to lead nowhere

---

Any ideas?

Comment: Isn't $ \dfrac{c_{n+1}}{c_n} = \sqrt{\dfrac{6+c_n}{3c_n^\color{red}2}} $?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Indeed it is, I edited thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prove by induction that

$\frac{c_{n+1}}{c_n} < a $ for all $n \ge k$

This would be an absolutely valid argument.

You just start your induction with $n=k$ instead of with $n=1$ as one usually does.

In general, one can define a sequence which is not monotonous up to $n < k$
but is monotonous for $n \ge k$. So your example here is one such case, it seems.

FYI here are the first several values:

```
1 5
2 1.9148542155126762
3 1.6242797599256802
4 1.5941852422607272
5 1.591035851498506
6 1.59070590739861
7 1.590671337035468
8 1.5906677148329322
9 1.5906673353064673
10 1.5906672955405086
11 1.5906672913739177
12 1.5906672909373514
13 1.5906672908916089
14 1.5906672908868162
15 1.590667290886314
16 1.5906672908862614
17 1.5906672908862558
18 1.5906672908862554
19 1.5906672908862554
20 1.5906672908862554
21 1.5906672908862554
```

From here you can make all sorts of hypotheses and prove them formally by induction.

Answer (score 0):

**Another way** is to look at the function $f(x)=\sqrt{2+\frac{x}{3}}$, where $c_{n+1}=f(c_n)$.

---

The first thing to observe is that $f'(x)=\frac{1}{6\sqrt{2+\frac{x}{3}}}>0, \forall x\geq0$, so the function is ascending $\forall x\geq0$.

---

The second observation is that $c_2=f(c_1)=\sqrt{\frac{11}{3}}<5=c_1$. Using the $1$st observation $$c_3=f(c_2)\leq f(c_1)=c_2$$
leading to $c_3\leq c_2<c_1$. Then $c_4=f(c_3)\leq f(c_2)=c_3$. By induction $$c_{n+1}\leq c_{n}$$
You already proved that $c_n>0, \forall n$, so you can apply [monotone convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem) to show convergence.